# Binding the meta key (a.k.a. super key / Windows key) to left click in Kubuntu

Tags: linux, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a program for Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 x64 that can bind the meta key (a.k.a. [super key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) / Windows key) to a left click: Hitting the meta key should trigger a left click, and pressing down on it should allow me to drag and drop (just like it would do when holding down left click).

(On Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can achieve that using the program [SmartNav](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html).)

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but that shouldn't need a specific software – but just an adjustment to the configuration (namely, "key-bindings"). I've just [checked on SU](http://superuser.com/search?q=keybindings+linux+answers%3A1), but found no specifics for "mouse"; you might ask for that over there, though.

Comment: PS: Suggesting [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+keybindings+mouse), brings up e.g. [Linux: Keyboard Tools for Key Layout, Keymapping, Keybinding](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html), or [Custom Key Bindings in Linux](http://dennisideler.com/blog/custom-key-bindings-in-linux/) mentioning [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) for configuration. See also the ["key-bindings" section in the KDE manual](https://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-utils/krusader/key_bindings.html).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, [I tried to use the native system setting](http://askubuntu.com/q/545361/44876), but I didn't find a way to set "meta" alone as being a shortcut. Regarding xbindkeys [I didn't find how to allow to drag and drop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166121/16704) (and I'm not even sure meta alone can be used as a shortcut, although I haven't looked at this thoroughly yet).

Comment: Thanks for the update, Franck! Didn't know you've already looked into that. I'm not using any such bindings, so I unfortunately don't know of a "proven solution" (hece the above as comments, not answers).